# Do I need an air breather box ? My mechanic told me I don’t

Tags: engine

The car I’m about to purchase has no air box and the seller has told me .. I do not need an air breather box ? I was told I do not need one. Any help would be great that.

Comment: Yes, the breather box, which is where the air filter is normally placed, is a required component for engine reliability and emissions.  I recommend that you PASS on purchasing this vehicle and look for one that doesn't have missing parts.

Comment: Also the lady is now telling me it’s the Sound box that’s missing?? I have no idea

Comment: OK, that's not as important - on the RCZ, it's basically an acoustic box on the headers which makes the engine sound better. However, I'd want to know why it was removed, and who removed it. And I'd still be shouting that over my shoulder as I was running away.. You don't know what other bits (maybe more important) have been removed along with it.

Answer (score 1):

Run, don't walk, away. The breather box is often quite a complex system with MAF sensors etc inside as well as the air filter. If the air filter is missing, your car is breathing all the gunk that gets caught by the filter - not good. Over time, the extra grime will wear the engine out. If an important sensor like the MAF is missing, the car will run badly anyway.

You don't state what the car make and model is, but I can pretty much guarantee that there are better options out there - with all parts intact.

Comment: Hey car is a Peugeot RCZ ?